# Refactoring across files in jedi-vim

Tags: python, jedi-vim

I know that refactoring within a file is possible via `leader-r`.
Is it possible to refactor code with jedi-vim across files, i.e. in the whole project?

Comment: This is not possible at the moment. We have to wait for https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1059 to be implemented.